# Problema com ordenação no PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, classificação, osx

Estou com um problema na hora de ordenar colunas no PostgreSQL apesar de estar configurado corretamente em UTF-8.

A versão do PostgreSQL é 9.3 e ele está instalando em um MacOSX Maverick 10.9.5 (este problema já ocorreu em versões anteriores do sistema).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando mando ordenar a coluna 'nome' no phpPgAdmin, Django ou pelo terminal, o PostgreSQL não está lidando com caracteres maiúsculos, minúsculos e acentos de forma correta.

Veja a tabela ordenada como está ficando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode observar, caracteres minúsculos estão ficando depois de caracteres maiúsculos, e caracteres com acentos estão ficando por último.

Quero que independente de ter acentos, ser maiúsculo ou minúsculo, que a ordenação seja realizada corretamente. Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: Não é exatamente uma solução, mas experimente ordenar por `lower(nome)` (que é basicamente o que uma coluna CITEXT faz automaticamente).

Comment: Já experimentou explicitar na query a comparação? Tipo `select * from tabela order by nome collate "pt_BR";` Ou talvez isso combinado com o `lower(nome)`. Não sei se vai funcionar, pois pelo que tenho lido uma ordenação que ao mesmo tempo respeite acentos e ignore capitalização é problemática, mas fica aí a sugestão...

Comment: @Bacco o problema é que apenas isso não é suficiente, eu queria mesmo era alterar alguma configuração do PostgreSQL para que retornasse do jeito que eu quero sem a necessidade disso.

Comment: @mgibsonbr a última vez que tive esse problema fui obrigado a criar uma nova coluna para cada campo que necessitasse de ordenação e filtro, sendo estas novas colunas tratadas para não ter acentos e caracteres maiúsculas, assim altero a ordem da coluna tratada, mas mostro o resultado da coluna original. Devido aos recursos do sistema e quantidade de tabelas, fica inviável esse tipo de query como você sugeriu. A saída vai ser eu recorrer o que eu fazia antigamente.

Comment: Por desencargo, qual o collation da coluna nome ?

Comment: use citext referencia no link :http://simplesideias.com.br/usando-campos-case-insensitive-no-postgresql

Comment: @gmsantos a tabela está sendo gerada pelo Django, e o banco está configurado para `lc_collate pt_BR.UTF-8`

Comment: @Bacco mas só deixar minúsculo não é suficiente, preciso que na leitura não faça distinção quando houver acentos, por isso estou sendo obrigado a ter duas colunas 'nome' e 'sort_nome', sendo que na primeira é gravada o texto original e na segunda o texto sem acentos e minúsculo. Dessa forma funciona perfeitamente, ao buscar palavras sem colocar acento, retorna também os que tem acento. O único problema é o conteúdo duplicado apenas para funcionar corretamente a ordenação e a busca.

Comment: @Bacco lembro que com mysql não tinha esse problema, a questão é que fica inviável alterar tabela por tabela, até porque elas são criadas dinamicamente e a qualquer momento podem ser recriadas/alteradas, fora quando é rodado testes e não tenho controle sobre isso.

Comment: @Orion postei um teste no SQL Fiddle com collation no 9.3 e aparentemente ficou em ordem.

Answer (score 3):

O PostgreSQL utiliza as colações fornecidas pelo sistema. Verifique quais estão disponíveis:

```
$ locale -a
```

No Linux Fedora a colação "pt_BR" funciona corretamente. Tente outras colações na sua consulta. Note que só as colações para a codificação UTF-8 vão funcionar na base UTF-8:

```
select * 
from t 
order by nome collate "pt_PT" -- ou "en_US"
```

Se nenhuma colação funcionar você ainda pode, para efeito de teste, criar uma base na codificação `LATIN1` (ISO-88591) e tentar de novo as colações.

O seu maior problema é que o OSX não deveria ser utilizado em um servidor de produção. Se houver oportunidade tente ou sugira às autoridades de plantão uma distribuição Linux.

Comment: Ainda continua o mesmo problema, deve ser alguma config no OSX relacionado ao postgresql que está ocasionando isso

Answer (score 2):

O ideal é especificar o *encoding* e o *collation* na hora de criar a base de dados, para que as futuras tabelas fiquem sempre do jeito desejado:

```
CREATE DATABASE name ENCODING 'UTF8 LC_COLLATE 'pt_BR'
```

Uma possível alternativa é especificar o *collation* na própria coluna:

```
CREATE TABLE alfabetica (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    nome TEXT COLLATE "pt_BR"
);
```

Veja um exemplo funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8a163/3)**.

Comment: Não adianta, fiz exatamente o que você disse e o problema continua, deve ser alguma configuração do postgresql no macosx

Comment: @Orion pena não poder ajudar, não tenho nem como testar direito aqui. Mas vamos torcer pra alguém com experiência em Pg e um MAC poste alguma alternativa. Acho que vou deixar a resposta aqui mesmo assim, pro caso de outro usuário com outro OS ter uma referência. Mas se descobrir algo, poste uma resposta sua, ou dê um feedback se puder.

Answer (score 0):

Não sou experiente em PostgreSQL para dizer que não haja nada errado com seu banco, mas sou experiente o suficiente com Mac para dizer que há um problema com o OS X.

Por padrão, as opções de `locale` do Mac são apenas links simbólicos para outras opções.

Na minha versão (Sierra), por exemplo, o `LC_COLLATE` do `"pt_BR.UTF-8"` aponta para o `LC_COLLATE` do `"la_LN.US-ASCII"`.

Isso é um mega problema (pra não dizer um absurdo) em vários sentidos, mas na prática o que isso significa é que qualquer biblioteca que dependa do collate do sistema funcionará de forma errada.

Concordo com o @Clodoaldo de que o melhor é tirar o OS X da produção.

Answer (score -1):

*Resposta atrasada mas talvez ainda seja útil para alguém:*

A única solução que funcionou para mim foi usar o encoding **LATIN1** em vez de UTF-8, e com o collation **pt_BR.ISO8859-1** que já estava instalado nativamente no meu mac (MacOS Catalina 10.5.5).

Segue o comando que eu usei:

**create database teste encoding "LATIN1" lc_collate "pt_BR.ISO8859-1" lc_ctype "pt_BR.ISO8859-1" template template0;**

Com isto, a ordenação funcionou respeitando os caracteres acentuados.

**Observações:**

*- O encoding LATIN1 é mais limitado que o UTF-8. Por exemplo, você não pode incluir nos campos de texto caracteres que não sejam compatíveis com as línguas latinas (como caracteres gregos ou alguns caracteres especiais), nem emoticons, etc. Estas coisas são suportadas no UTF-8. Mas dependendo da necessidade do seu banco de dados, isto não seja necessário e o LATIN1 atenda à sua necessidade.*

*- Cuidado se for restaurar um backup de base que usava UTF-8 em uma nova base criada em LATIN1. Isto pode fazer as letras acentuadas ficarem todas embaralhadas. Mas no meu caso não aconteceu, funcionou legal.*